# How do I to print out the average of each row of a 2D array separately?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, average

The assignment I have is to find the average of the temps in each row of the array. There are 3 rows. I have to find the average of the 3 rows separately, not together, and then print out the averages like so:

```
Avg for student 1 is x
Avg for students 2 is A
Avg for student 3 is h.
```

This is the actual assignment paper:

> Name this program `testScoresArray`.
> Write a program that stores the following temps in a 2D array.
>
> ```
> Student 1: 100, 80, 93
> Student 2: 74, 83, 91, 87
> Student 3: 94, 98
> ```
>
> Find the average temp for EACH student separately.
> Hint: you need to keep track of the score but after every time it loops through a column and finds the average, you need to set the value of the score back to 0 or it will count the previous scores!
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> ```
> Average temp for Student 1: 91.0
> Average temp for Student 2: 83.75
> Average temp for Student 3: 96.0
> ```

This is the code I have right now. I need to find a way to find the averages separately and print them the way above. I can't seem to do that. Can anyone help me, please?

```java
public class testScoresArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] temps = {{100, 80, 93}, {74, 83, 91, 87}, {94, 98}};
        for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int g = 0; g < temps[i].length; g++) {
                sum += temps[i][g];
            }
            System.out.println(sum / temps[i].length);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best, but the easiest solution would be to simply change the type of sum to float or double

```
float sum = 0;
```

This will make the division that happens on the println to change from integer division to a floating point one, if only one of the operands has a floating point then your print will have a dot

Answer (score 0):

Single-semicolon solution using streams:

```java
int[][] temps = {{100, 80, 93}, {74, 83, 91, 87}, {94, 98}};
```

```java
// iterating over row indices
IntStream.range(0, temps.length)
        // print the beginning of each row
        .peek(i -> System.out.print("Average temp for Student "+(i+1)+": "))
        // take the average of the row
        .mapToDouble(i -> Arrays.stream(temps[i]).average().orElse(0.0))
        // print the average value and the line break
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Average temp for Student 1: 91.0
Average temp for Student 2: 83.75
Average temp for Student 3: 96.0
```

---

<sup>See also: [Searching for average temperature for all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66752561/15402945)</sup>